# Can anyone identify these Bionicle sets?

Tags: set-identification, bionicle

Can anyone identify these Lego pieces? They were given to us in a bin of toys, and we cannot identify them. We know they're Lego, and have a 2002 date on them.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those appear to be Bionicle figures, a theme that was active from 2001 to 2009 (and making a comeback in 2015, I hear). The line focused on buildable "action figures" (aka "constraction figures").

See here: http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Bionicle

Answer (score 3):

The yellow one is the Glatorian-era Mata Nui, the red one with the staff is a Toa Nuva-era Rahkshi (Turahk, to be specific), and the green spider-thing is a Toa Hordika-era Visorak (Keelerak) that has been placed upside-down.

The other four are Metru Nui Matoran, without their masks; the lighting makes it hard to tell what elements they correspond to, but the ice one appears to have the wrong head.

Turahk: http://brickset.com/sets/8592-1

Keelerak: http://brickset.com/sets/8746-1/Visorak-Keelerak

Can't post other links due to reputation; sorry about that.